# Confused about concatenating arrays in javascript resulting in a bug

Tags: javascript

So I have one array and I want to have array1 += array2 where array1 could either be [] or an array of strings. For example I would like to see var array1 = ["abc", "def"] var array2 = ["ghi", "jkl"] and then array1 += array2 would result in array being equal to ["abc", "def", "ghi", "jkl"] but instead when I do array += array2 I get array1 is equal to ["abc", "def", "ghi, jkl"]. Is there some other way of concatenating the two arrays?

Comment: `var arr3 = arr1.concat(arr2);` [Array.prototype.concat()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat)

Comment: `+` performs **string** concatenation or addition, but not array concatenation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easily done with concat method:

```
array1.concat(array2);
```